# My Toyota Corolla 2009 Le 1.8l fuel consumption too high

Tags: toyota, fuel-consumption, corolla

I run my car in normal use in highway and no traffic I spend $20 full tank 90 miles I replace my tires,spark plugs Oem ,Transmission fluid with filter,Engine oil with filter,Thermostat,antifreeze,Air filter,replace the Ignition Coils and no codes are present I just need some good person out there that can give a good advise on this issue what will be the next procedure to correct this dilemma for this issue started a month ago and Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you had the vehicle checked for fuel leaks? 
Do you ever smell gas when you get out after driving it?

Comment: No fuel leaks so far and I already check the front lines to the injectors and from the gas tank too.

Comment: no gas smell at all?

Comment: Please provide fuel economy numbers before and after. Knowing the difference will assist with narrowing down what it could be.

Comment: What are your revs while highway driving? Could be a transmission problem

Comment: Do you have to have the emissions tested? Does it pass? If you don't have to get emissions tested, perhaps a garage can do an emissions test that might yield additional clues.

Comment: Similar to above; has this always happened with this car?  If not, what changed besides fuel consumption. How long did it function properly and how long has it been using too much fuel. I can't even imagine how you get through an entire tank of fuel in 90 miles. It seems like they'red be some clue? YOu should be getting more than triple that mileage.

Comment: I couldn't find any info online, is this by any chance a Direct Injection engine? I"m not even sure if Toyota offered such a thing.

Comment: I can’t see how $20 would fill a tank ? Are you sure the actual tank is full ? The gauge might read full but you may only have 1/4 tank

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your intake valves? its a longshot but maybe

Comment: My car have 127,000 miles on it and I always use Shell gas 91 octane and I don't think my intake valves are bad and thanks for the thought

Answer (score 0):

Compression test the engine - if you have low compression, you will have poor fuel economy  - (this is how you test for the intake valve concern the other poster metioned)

Use the OBD scan tool to check the fuel trims to see if you are running rich (excessive fuel)

A fuel injector could be leaking - causing your car to run rich - the fuel would still go into one of the cylinders, thus it would get burned. A a bad oxygen sensor could also be causing the car to run rich - does the exhaust of the vehicle smell odd.

I would take the car to a mechanic if you cannot figure it out yourself soon, because running rich will damage your catalytic converter - and that will be expensive.